# Python Maze Generation Script - Converting to Javascript: Differences in Maths?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, maze

I have a maze generator script in Python (3.4) that I am trying to convert to Javascript. The original Python script can be found below:

```
import random

width = 10
height = 10
difficulty = 5

walls = []
maze = [0] * width

for i in range(height):
    maze[i] = [0] * height

maze[0][1] = 1

walls.append([1, 1, 1])

print(random.random())

def addWalls():
    walls.append([X + 1, Y, 1])
    walls.append([X - 1, Y, 2])
    walls.append([X, Y + 1, 3])
    walls.append([X, Y - 1, 4])
    maze[X][Y] = 1

while len(walls) > 0:
    if len(walls) > difficulty:
        current = len(walls) - round(random.random() * difficulty) - 1
    else:
        current = round(random.random() * (len(walls) - 1))

    cell = walls[current]
    walls.pop(current)

    X = cell[0]
    Y = cell[1]
    Dir = cell[2]

    if Dir == 1:
        if X + 1 < width and maze[X][Y] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 and maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X][Y + 1] == 0:
            addWalls()
    elif Dir == 2:
        if X - 1 >  - 1 and maze[X][Y] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 and maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X][Y + 1] == 0:
            addWalls()
    elif Dir == 3:
        if Y + 1 < height and maze[X][Y] == 0 and maze[X][Y + 1] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y] == 0:
            addWalls()
    elif Dir == 4:
        if Y - 1 >  - 1 and maze[X][Y] == 0 and maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 and maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 and maze[X + 1][Y] == 0:
            addWalls()

for y in range(0, height):
    line = ''
    for x in range(0, width):
        if (maze[x][y] == 0):
            line += '0'
        else:
            line += '1'
    print(line)
```

The script works as it should, however when trying to accomplish the same in Javascript, the maze seems to stop traversing. See the snippet below (0 = wall, 1 = open space in the maze):

```js
function newLevel(dimensions, difficulty) {

  // create arrays
  walls = [
    [1, 1, 1]
  ];
  maze = [];

  for (i = 0; i < dimensions - 1; i++) {
    maze[i] = [0];
    for (j = 0; j < dimensions - 1; j++) {
      maze[i][j] = [0];
    }
  }

  // set the cell (0; 1) as the exit
  maze[0][1] = 1;

  function addwalls() {
    walls.push([X + 1, Y, 1]);
    walls.push([X - 1, Y, 2]);
    walls.push([X, Y + 1, 3]);
    walls.push([X, Y - 1, 4]);
    maze[X][Y] = 1;
  }

  while (walls.length > 0) {
    current = Math.round(Math.random() * (walls.length - 1));
    if (walls.length > difficulty) {
      current = walls.length - Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty) - 1;
    }
    cell = walls[current];
    walls.pop(current);

    X = cell[0];
    Y = cell[1];
    Dir = cell[2];

    if (Dir == 1 && X + 1 < dimensions && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y + 1] == 0) {
      addwalls();
    }
    if (Dir == 2 && X - 1 > -1 && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y + 1] == 0) {
      addwalls()
    }
    if (Dir == 3 && Y + 1 < dimensions && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y] == 0) {
      addwalls();
    }
    if (Dir == 4 && Y - 1 > -1 && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y] == 0) {
      addwalls();
    }
  }

  cells = maze;

  for (var row = 0; row < maze.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++) {
      $('body').append(maze[row][col]);
    }
    $('body').append('<br />');
  }

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  newLevel(30, 5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

</body>
```

Are there any major differences in the way that Maths is done between Python and Javascript?

Thanks

EDIT: Thank you very much for your support. Here is the working script:

```
function newLevel(dimensions, difficulty) {

  // create arrays
  walls = [[1, 1, 1]];
  maze = [];

  for (i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    maze[i] = [0];
    for (j = 0; j < dimensions; j++) {
      maze[i][j] = [0];
    }
  }

  // set the cell (0; 1) as the exit
  maze[0][1] = 1;

  function addwalls() {
    walls.push([X + 1, Y, 1]);
    walls.push([X - 1, Y, 2]);
    walls.push([X, Y + 1, 3]);
    walls.push([X, Y - 1, 4]);
    maze[X][Y] = 1;
  }

  while (walls.length > 0) {
    current = Math.round(Math.random() * (walls.length - 1));
    if (walls.length > difficulty) {
      current = walls.length - Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty) - 1;
    }

    cell = walls[current];
    walls.splice(current, 1)[0];

    X = cell[0];
    Y = cell[1];
    Dir = cell[2];

    if (Dir == 1 && X + 1 < dimensions && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y + 1] == 0) {
      addwalls();
    }
    if (Dir == 2 && X - 1 >  - 1 && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X][Y + 1] == 0) {
      addwalls()
    }
    if (Dir == 3 && Y + 1 < dimensions && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y] == 0) {
      addwalls();
    }
    if (Dir == 4 && Y - 1 >  - 1 && maze[X][Y] == 0 && maze[X][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y - 1] == 0 && maze[X - 1][Y] == 0 && maze[X + 1][Y] == 0) {
      addwalls();
    }
  }
  return cells;
}
```

Comment: For one, Javascript doesn't support integers.

Comment: @cjohnson318 That's interesting... What is the best way to represent an integer then? By rounding values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of tiny but easily neck-breaking differences between Python and JavaScript.

The loop in Python

```
for i in range(10)
```

rolls from 0 up to 9 in ten steps. You translated it into

```
for (i = 0; i < 10 - 1; i++)
```

which rolls from 0 to 8 in nine steps (assuming the value of `height` is equal to `dimensions`).

You cannot choose which element to `pop` out of a JavaScript array you need [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do so (or roll your own, of course).

Regarding the integer problem:
JavaScript's `Number` object is a 64-bit floating point number, better known as an IEEE-754 binary64 double. That restricts the range of integers to `-2^53 < x < 2^53`. You can "persuade" the engine to handle some numbers `x` as signed integers by `x|0` and as unsigned integers as by `x>>>0` but the automatic conversion tries to sneak in in every possible way, preferable the most unexpected ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that, in python, pop appears to be able to remove any element from an array. In javascript, [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the *last* element of an array, and it takes no arguments. To remove an arbitrary element from an array in javscript, use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which can remove and add elements at a given index:

```
cell = walls[current];
walls.pop(current);
```

becomes

```
cell = walls.splice(current, 1)[0];
```

What this does is it removes 1 element from the array walls starting at the index current. Splice returns an array of elements removed, so cell is the first element of that array.